# How can i use Dialog Box From non activity Class?

Tags: java, android

I am new in Android, I want to open a dialog from non activity class , which shows that Do You Want to Quit ? No/Yes

Comment: Nope. You can not show `Dialog` without `Activity` reference. but you can show System Alert Dialog which requires a `Context` and user permission...

Comment: read this,for all models of Dialogs : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: In MainActivity I use this method public void alertbox() { { AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); builder.setMessage("Blah").setCancelable(false) .setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) { dialog.cancel(); } }); AlertDialog alert = builder.create(); alert.show(); } } i am caling this method from my class but my Application Crash Whyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy?

Answer (score 2):

If you have logic in a class outside of the Activity, and based on this logic you want to show an AlertDialog, you can do either of the following:

1. Pass the Activity instance into your other class' method so that you can use this in the AlertDialog.Builder constructor (not recommended)
2. Send a BroadcastIntent to be received by your activity, and in the activity's BroadcastReceiver you can then construct your AlertDialog from there.

Option 2 is cleaner as it is pretty bad practice to pass Activity instances around through your code.  You mentioned in your question that you're new to Android, so if you're not familiar with BroadcastIntent, BroadcastReceiver, and AlertDialog.Builder, do some Googling and/or leave a comment with specific questions and I'll update my answer.

**EDIT IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT**

You shouldn't expose public methods from your Activity in the way you described.  The logic inside your activity should be deciding when to show an alert box and shouldn't be told to do so from elsewhere in your application.  The better question is: where are you calling this from?

Also, a very important thing to note: When asking questions on StackOverflow about a crash in your application, ALWAYS post the error and stack trace from LogCat.

Comment: In MainActivity I use this method    

    public void alertbox() 
    {
 {
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      builder.setMessage("Blah").setCancelable(false)
        .setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                 
             
             dialog.cancel();
             }
        });
 AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
 alert.show();
      }
  
    }

i am caling this method from my class



but my Application Crash Whyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy?